# Item checked when created in android listview

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

I am trying to create an alarm system for my android app, and I have a `listview` in which I am adding the alamrs. This `listview` adapter is an `simple_list_item_multiple_choice`. I want that when I add an alarm this appears as checked in the `listview`, but I have not found the solution for that.

This code is not working as I expected:

```
{
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, this.alarmList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter); 
    list.setItemChecked(itemPos, true); 
}
```

Do you know what else could I try?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude try this code i hope that is that you mean:

```
final SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
final  ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, this.alarmList);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        list.setAdapter(adapter );
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //SparseBooleanArray Checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
                if(!mSelectedItemsIds.get(position)){
                   list.setItemChecked(position, true);
                    mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, true);
                }
                else{
                    mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
                    list.setItemChecked(position, false);
                }



            }
        });
```

Edit:  i set the list as final, make sure you do it also if you didnt otherwise it wont work

Comment: No, I think this code is to create a listener for when an item is tapped it gets checked or unchecked, but what I need is that the item gets selected when I create it

Comment: ahhh ok then you need a CustomAdapter and do check on getView method

Comment: So there is no other option? Should I create a CustomAdapter?

Comment: if you want to get the item selected yes you should change the getView method on you adapter

Answer (score 1):

multiple_choice.xml

```
<CheckedTextView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     

  android:id="@+id/checkList" 
  android:paddingLeft="20dip" 
  android:paddingRight="20dip" 
  android:paddingTop="10dip"
  android:paddingBottom="10dip" 
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"  
  android:gravity="center_vertical"  
  android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```

> 

in your java file

```
final ListAdapter ladapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                     R.layout.multiple_choice, <string array>);

       listView.setAdapter(ladapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                listView.setItemChecked(2, true);
```

this will set the 3rd item in the listview to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you still need to call [adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).

This notifies the adapter to update the contents of the list to display the changes you made to it.

Comment: After you updated the list's dataset, so yeah, I'd say place it after the code you specified.