# ListView does not show CheckedItems

Tags: android, listview

ListView does not show the Checked items that I want to add by default.

```
String[] allComplaintActions = POCValues.pocMap.get(chiefComplaint.getSelectedItem().toString());
    ArrayAdapter<String> actionArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, allComplaintActions);
    actionList.setAdapter(actionArrayAdapter);
    Log.d(TAG, "Count : " + actionList.getCount());
    actionList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    actionList.setItemChecked(2, true);
    Log.d(TAG, "CheckedItem: "+ actionList.getCheckedItemPosition());
```

Will Spit out this Log

> Count : 4
>
> CheckedItem: 2

but the remains completely blank.

I am on an emulator. Could that be the problem?

This is what I see
[Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EiUU.png)

But "Something more reasonable" should be checked

Comment: please add any image as sample for expected result.

Comment: @ austin : Add code for your adapter also..!!

Comment: there is no code for my Adapter besides what's here. I'm just using the arrayAdapter

Comment: Please refer this link
[Listview with checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907598/item-checked-when-created-in-android-listview)

Answer (score 0):

change android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice to android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. As it turns out my onItemSelected (for my spinner which changes the list based on the selection) was being called on the start of the Activity.